# Angular: Validate form with multiple child components

Tags: angular

Using Angular 6 here:

I have a parent component and within that I have 3 child components. 
The child 1 component has a text fields, child 2 component has a dropdown and child 3 component has a dropdown and a submit button.

On the submit click button of child 3, I want to validate all the inputs of child1, child2 and child3 as they are required and throw error accordingly.

With angularjs I can just bind to ngmodel and check if form is invalid. How can I do so in angular? I mean how can I get and pass the state of input from one child to another etc.
When searching I found the concept of reactive forms but most of the articles are of parents forms having input only.

Would appreciate if anyone can provide help on this. Below is the code I have

--Updated--

I updated below code after following this post: https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664

But this one keeps on giving me error in console: "*Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).*"

--Updated code with reactive form--

```
--Parent--

<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="row">     
      <ct-child1  [myForm]="myForm"></ct-child1>          
      <ct-child2> </ct-child2>      
    </div>
    <div class="row">      
      <ct-child3></ct-child3>         
    </div>   
</form>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit  {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
      this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      uname: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    }  
 }

 --Child 1--

<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="myForm" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uname" [formControlName]="'uname'"  placeholder="Enter Name..." required >
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html']
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit { 
  @Input() myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor() { }
  uname: string; 

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: Reactive forms is an excellent and great idea, go ahead with that :)

Comment: Have the submit button in the parent, using the reactive form, you have all values and validity of all form fields in parent no matter if the fields are in child component or parent. In parent you can do what you need to do on form submit :)

Comment: @AJT_82 thanks will try and let you know.

Comment: Do you need the submit in the third child component?

Comment: @AJT_82 I have updated my code with reactive form but its giving me error. Not sure whats missing here. I followed the post at: https://medium.com/@joshblf/using-child-components-in-angular-forms-d44e60036664

Comment: You have marked the formgroup on label. It should wrap your formcontrol(s), so for example mark `[formGroup]="myForm"` on the div that wraps the label and input. Also, do not use `ngModel` with formcontrolname :)

Comment: @AJT_82 done that, it still give errors

Answer (score 5):

Build the form in your parent, pass whatever fields, or nested formgroups you want to the children. Parent will be aware of anything that goes on in the children. It knows if a specific form control is valid or not, is the whole form valid... all that it needs to know about the form!

Build the form in your parent, pass whatever fields you want. If you do not have nested formgroups that are passed to children, you need to pass the whole parentform to the child(ren), because all fields that are shown in the child components need to be wrapped inside a formgroup. What we are seing in your example is that you want to pass the whole form as `@Input` to the child(ren) just like you have. Then in your child, **wrap** the fields within the formgroup, just like a "regular" form:

```html
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="uname"  placeholder="Enter Name...">
</div>
```

Also remove the brackets from `formControlName`, since you are not trying to use a variable binding, your formcontrol is simply named `uname`. Also you don't need anything like marking `required` in the template, since this is handled by the form when you set `Validators.required` (or whatever **[validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators)** you want).

Showing validation errors you can use with calling `hasError()`, so in this sample `myForm.hasError('required', 'uname')` can be set with `*ngIf`.

And as I mentioned, have the submit button in the parent, since the parent controls the whole form. I guess you **can** have the button in child 3, but I see no point in making it overcomplicated and needing go up in the tree to get a hold of the parent form, when it's easily done having it in the parent, and that is also how it's recommended to do:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ct-child1 [myForm]="myForm"></ct-child1>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**[Here's a sample for you](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4flgpf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**. Just having one child, but you can have as many different childs you like, just follow the same pattern as we did with child 1 :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It works for most part. Just one thing the validation does not fire when I press the submit button. Is it possible to somehow manually fire all the validation when on submit I find that form is not valid. I used your example to create form as https://angular-wuchy7.stackblitz.io Here I just added form.touched to the control. How can I fire the validation or show the error on submit click.

Comment: any inputs on my above query ?

Answer (score 2):

I would move the submit button in child 3 component into the parent component then you can use `@ViewChild()` to get a reference to the child components and the forms in the component which will allow you to check the validity of them.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit  {

    @ViewChild(Child1Component) child1Component: Child1Component; 
    @ViewChild(Child2Component) child2Component: Child2Component;
    @ViewChild(Child3Component) child3Component: Child3Component;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}  

    submitlClicked() {
        //check if form is valid, else throw error
        if (this.child1Component.myFormGroup.valid 
            && this.child2Component.myFormGroup.valid 
            && this.child3Component.myFormGroup.valid) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // throw error
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to change your code and use `Reactive Forms` (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms):

```
-- Child 1 --

<form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
  <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name:</label>
         <div class="col-sm-8">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uname" formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter Name..." required>
         </div>
      </div>      
   </div>
</form>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-child1',
  templateUrl: './child1.component.html']
})
export class Child1Component implements OnInit {

    myFormGroup: FormGroup; 

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        myFormGroup = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    } 

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: see my updated post with code I have used with reactive form and error I am getting. I have form in my parent and not in my child as per your code.

Comment: @karen you need to wrap the whole template in `<form>` tags and put the `[formGroup]` directive on the `<form>` tag not individual inputs/labels.

Comment: I have updated my code as per your inputs(see my updated post) and now its giving error: Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Comment: So the code that I have works if the controls are in parent which is simple. But with child component I am not able to figure out whats missing here,